# how to integrate with already authenticated by using aws cognito service with aws copilot cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-copilot, aws-copilot-cli

how to integrate with already authenticated by using aws cognito service with aws copilot cli

if there is possible to integrate with  aws cognito services(already authenticate with application load balance to aws copilot cli

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting the answer from https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/3374:

You can use Copilot's [add-ons](https://aws.github.io/copilot-cli/docs/developing/additional-aws-resources/#how-to-do-i-add-other-resources) functionality to add a CFN template to integrate with AWS Cognito. [Here](https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/2050#issuecomment-812838310) is a sample template from a Copilot user.